# Which version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll cures "DataReader.GetFieldType returned null" bug for SQL Server 2017?

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I'm developing a C# app on a x64 dev box running Windows 10, VS 2017 and SQL Server 2017 (ver 14.0.1000.169, Developer Edition (64-bit)). I'm testing my app with the `AdventureWorks2016` database. Reading a `[HumanResources].[Employee]` record throws the well-documented `"DataReader.GetFieldType returned null"` exception for the `OrganizationNode` field whose datatype is `hierarchyId`.

I've tried the fixes from the top 2 answers described in the SO question [DataReader.GetFieldType returned null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569624/datareader-getfieldtype-returned-null) but they didn't work for me:

1. I tried the copies of the dll available on my machine (i.e., added a ref to the dll and made it `local copy = true`):

   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies`
   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin`
   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies`
   - There are no copies of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` (so, I assume, no 64-bit version of the dll are on my machine).
2. Modifying the connection string with `"Type System Version=SQL Server 2012"` didn't work either

I know my sql connection and `"Fill"` command works because it works fine when I read records from `AdventureWorks2016` tables that don't have a `hierarchyId`, `geography`, or `geometry` field.

```
sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.CommandText = primaryKeyQueryString;

SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Do you know which version of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` will cure my problem for SQL Server 2017?

If so where can I get a copy of it?

Do I need to install an older SQL server dll and distribute it with my app?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've done:

I installed Microsoft.SqlServer.Types from nugget and you should have in the bin a folder called SqlServerTypes\x64 and x86 that also should be deployed with your app, beside the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll in the bin folder

When installed from nugget, you also have a new folder in your code called SQLServerTypes\Loader.cs (Convert it to VB if using VB) that loads some low level dependencies (msvcr1x0.dll and SqlServerSpatial1x0.dll).

On my server with SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2019, I could only make this work by installing Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version 11.0.2. Recent versions didn't solved the issue.

When I referenced these versions, the GetFieldType recognized the spatial types and everything worked smoothly.

After some time digging on this problem I recommend trying other versions if the problem persist because that is what solve this issue.

Also confirm that your SQL Server installation has the Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2017 installed. If not, you must install them from Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Feature Pack or from the SQL Server Setup
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55992

These steps work for all versions of SQL Server. If anyone is experiencing any issue don't lose time thinking it's a server missing dll's issue, just try different versions of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types from Nugget as an older or a newer version will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Win 7 machine having versions of the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` not on my Win 10 machine. I tested each DLL  from both my Win 10 machine and the Win 7 machine in turn using an explicit reference. Here are the results:

1. 2009.100.2500.0, (6-17-2011) works
2. 2014.120.2000.8 (2/21/2014) fails
3. 2014.120.5000.0,  (6-18-2016) fails
4. 2011.110.2832.25, (8-15-2017) fails
5. 2017.140.1000.169, (8-22-2017) fails
6. 2017.140.500.272,  (2-1-2018) fails

Answer (score 0):

Using (the oldest) version 10.50.1600.1 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

copy Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll to root folder of your project and change references in project to this file (delete old and set new reference)
Like this: c:\Work\WindowsApp1\

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34881740)